# 1TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am new at pymongo, but have a decent knowledge on mongoDB
So basically I have a list of strings, then I converted it into a dictionary using key as integer, so as pymongo doesn't allow integer keys, I converted that dictionary to json using json.dumps()
and then tried inserting into the DB. But its showing this error : TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping

Sample code:

```
 list = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
    dict1 = {}
    for i in range(0, len(list)):
        dict1[i] = list[i]
json1 = json.dumps(dict1)
    connection = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
    db = connection["test"]
    collection1 = db["test"]
    collection1.insert_one(json1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert the dictionary to json, you can just insert the dictionary and that will work just fine.

```
collection1.insert_one(dict1)
```